# import nltk error in xampp, or on wamp

Tags: python, xampp, cgi, wamp, nltk

I am using nltk (installed and works fine in IDLE) for  a project in Python (2.7.4) which runs perfectly fine on IDLE, but using the same code in xampp or wamp (cgi-bin), everything related to 'nltk' doesn't works and this is the error shown by adding these lines

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

The errors are in lines are marked by '=>' and details are enclosed within ** and **. I've tried printing 'sys.path' after importing os, which shows the 'site-packages' directory in which 'nltk' resides. I even copied and pasted this folder into 'C:\Python27\' but still the same errors. Things other than nltk works as desired.

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>  Python 2.7.4: C:\python27\python.exe
Wed May 14 16:13:34 2014


A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls 
leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.


C:\xampp\cgi-bin\Major\project.py in ()
=>   73 import nltk

**nltk undefined**




C:\python27\nltk\__init__.py in ()
    159     import cluster; from cluster import *
    160 
=>  161 from downloader import download, download_shell
    162 try:
    163     import Tkinter

**downloader undefined, download undefined, download_shell undefined**



C:\python27\nltk\downloader.py in ()
   2199 
   2200 # Aliases
=> 2201 _downloader = Downloader()
   2202 download = _downloader.download
   2203 def download_shell(): DownloaderShell(_downloader).run()

**_downloader undefined, Downloader = None**



C:\python27\nltk\downloader.py in __init__(self=<nltk.downloader.Downl
oader object>, server_index_url=None, download_dir=None)
    425         # decide where we're going to save things to.
    426         if self._download_dir is None:
=>  427             self._download_dir = self.default_download_dir()
    428 
    429     #/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**self = <nltk.downloader.Downloader object>, self._download_dir = None,
self.default_download_dir = <bound method Downloader.default_download_dir of 
<nltk.downloader.Downloader object>>**




C:\python27\nltk\downloader.py in default_download_dir(self=<nltk.downloa
der.Downloader object>)
    926             homedir = os.path.expanduser('~/')
    927             if homedir == '~/':
=>  928                 raise ValueError("Could not find a default 
download directory")
    929 
    930         # append "nltk_data" to the home directory

**<pre>builtin ValueError = < type 'exceptions.ValueError' > <pre/>**



<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Could not find a default download directory
      args = ('Could not find a default download directory',)
      message = 'Could not find a default download directory'
```